# FOS Facebook Bundle - User logged out at next visit

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, symfony

in my symfony 2.3 application I added FOS Facebook to handle the login.
The login works great (thanks to stack overflow!).

But the following scenario fails:

1. user uses fosfacebook to login
2. user closes website without logging out, of course the php sessions end and symfony sees the user as anonymous.
3. next time the user come to the website, the user will be redirected to the login page, but     **javascript facebook button shows "logout"** instead of  login.

So I see 2 solutions:

1. Replace javascript facebook button buy I self coded redirect (?)
2. Detect on server-side, that the user is already logged in with facebook and foster the login.

What do you recommend?
Thank you for your help!

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I use this with facebook api implementations in my Symfony2 projects... with fos and hwi:

```
 {% if app.user %}
    # user is logged in => show picture, and other stuff
 {% else %}
    # user is not logged in => show button
 {% endif %}
```

alternatively you can use Facebook JS API to get the status of the user and autologin if `response.status === 'connected'`